# Using Regular Expression to Redirect Blog Posts

Tags: regex, redirect

We are migrating our websites and some of the old URLS are no longer valid, so I'm struggling with writing a Regex script to handle the move.

Here's what I am changing:

```
/blog/post/231-Do-Swimming-Pool-Solar-Covers-Really-Work-
```

to

```
Do-Swimming-Pool-Solar-Covers-Really-Work
```

Here's what I have so far:
Using: `^[^-]*-`
I can get rid of the `/blog/post/231-`

Using : `.{1}$`
I can get rid of the trailing `-`

I don't know how to get the two of them to work together to get my final result though. Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: Try `^[^-]*-(.*).$` and use `$1` in the redirection pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a capturing group that you will be able to refer to with `$1` backreference in the replacement:

```
^[^-]*-(.*)-$
```

This will match zero or more characters other than `-` (`[^-]*`) from the string start (`^`), then will match a `-`, capture any 0+ characters up to the `-` that is at the end (`$` of the string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dA5aX7/1)